# How to set up routes and redirect in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm building an app in React and using react-router-dom.

My current set up works in most cases, but it fails to render if the route is unknown and I don't think I'm using the best practice.

This is what I have:

index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
                <Route path="/" component={Main} />
            </Suspense>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Then in my Main.js class component, if the user is not authenticated, I render login page and `this.props.history.push('/login')`. If the user is authenticated I have the following routes:

```
{this.props.location.pathname === '/' || this.props.location.pathname.endsWith('dashboard') && <Dashboard />}
<Switch>
    {
        userAdmin &&
        <React.Fragment>
            <Route exact path="/users" component={Users} />
            <Route path="/users/:id" component={User} />
        </React.Fragment>
    }
    {
        productAdmin &&
        <React.Fragment>
            <Route exact path="/products" component={Products} />
            <Route path="/products/:id" component={Product} />
        </React.Fragment>
    }
    <Route component={Dashboard} />
</Switch>
```

I want to redirect authenticated user to `/` and render `Dashboard` if the route is not matched.

I added `<Route component={Dashboard} />`, it doesn't work.
I also tried with `<Redirect to="/dashboard" />` but it doesn't do anything.
I tried to remove switch, and then it seems like it works as expected, but it also redirects whenever I try to access directly any other existing route.

How should I set this up correctly?

Answer (score 0):

For routes needing authentication, you can create an abstraction of `PrivateRoute` accepting some `permissions`, `route` and `Component` as props. It will check if user has those permissions and will redirect to the `route` else it will redirect to the default page.
Refer:[Creating Private Routes](https://dev.to/karanpratapsingh/private-public-and-restricted-routes-in-react-42ff)

For pages accessible to all you can use `Route` component of `react-router`.

You can set your `Routes` component in the following manner:

```
...
<Switch>
   <PrivateRoute permission={userAdmin} route="/users" component={Users} /> 
   <PrivateRoute permission={productAdmin} route="/products" component={Products} />
   <Route path="/" component={Dashboard} />
//some more routes
</Switch>
```

Your `index.js` just needs to render `Routes` component

```
 ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
                <Routes />
            </Suspense>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```